# What is the best way to convert this java code into Objective C code?

Tags: java, objective-c

```
public byte[] toBytes() {
    size = 12;
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
    buf.putInt(type.ordinal());//type is a enum
    buf.putInt(id);
    buf.putInt(size);
    return buf.array();
}

@Override
public void fromBytes(byte[] data) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
    buf.put(data);
    buf.rewind();
    type = MessageType.values()[buf.getInt()];
    id = buf.getInt();
    size = buf.getInt();
}
```

I have two java methods and want to write an objective C method..
For the first method I wrote it into an Objective C code like

```
- (NSMutableData *) toBytes{
    size = 12;

    NSMutableData *buf = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:size];

    NSData *dataType = [NSData dataWithBytes: &type length: sizeof(type)];
    NSData *dataId = [NSData dataWithBytes: &msgId length: sizeof(msgId)];
    NSData *dataSize = [NSData dataWithBytes: &size length: sizeof(size)];

    [buf appendData:dataType];
    [buf appendData:dataId];
    [buf appendData:dataSize];

    [dataType release];
    [dataId release];
    [dataSize release];

    return buf;
}
```

But not sure how to read it back...
It could've been easier if I add only one data into the buffer
but I added total three data so I don't know how to read those back..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you want to do this manually, or automatically?  What have you tried, and where are you getting hung up?  Or do you simply want us to do the conversion for you (hint: we won't)?

Comment: Errr... by writing the Obj-C code?

Comment: wanted to by manually.. I think I need to create a buffer by NSMutableData and use appendBytes method to add bytes..and now I don't have any idea besides that...

Comment: Step 1: Learn Java. Step 2: Learn Objective-C. Step 3: ???. Step 4: Profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note to LCYSoft: i'm making this a community wiki. please correct any issues. i didn't compile this. since you posted one direction and *really* want an answer, i provided one. sorry, i am kinda busy atm.

this demonstrates both directions, and expands on the OP:

```
typedef enum t_mon_enum_type {
  MONEnum_Edno = 1,
  MONEnum_Dve = 2,
  MONEnum_Tre = 3
} t_mon_enum_type;

@interface MONObject : NSObject
{
    t_mon_enum_type type;
    int msgId;
    int size;
}

@end

@implementation MONObject

/* ... */

- (NSMutableData *)dataRepresentation
{
    const int typeAsInt = (int)type;
    const size_t capacity = sizeof(typeAsInt) + sizeof(msgId) + sizeof(size);
    NSMutableData * data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity];

    [data appendBytes:&typeAsInt length:sizeof(typeAsInt)];
    [data appendBytes:&msgId length:sizeof(msgId)];
    [data appendBytes:&size length:sizeof(size)];

    return [data autorelease];
}

- (BOOL)isDataRepresentationValid:(NSData *)data { /* @todo */ }

- (BOOL)restoreFromDataRepresentation:(NSData *)data
{
    if (![self isDataRepresentationValid]) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSRange range = { 0, 0 };

    int tmp = 0;
    /* restore `type` */
    range.length = sizeof(tmp);
    [data getBytes:&tmp range:range];
    type = (t_mon_enum_type)tmp;
    /* advance read position */
    range.location += range.length;
    /* restore `msgId` */
    range.length = sizeof(msgId);
    [data getBytes:&msgId range:range];
    /* advance read position */
    range.location += range.length;
    /*
       setting the length here is redundant in this case, but it's how we
       write it when dealing with more complex pod types.
     */
    range.length = sizeof(size);
    [data getBytes:&size range:range];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It has very minor errors like [buf autorelease](should be [data autorelease]). Besides that it works great :) Thanks you so much. I really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: @LCYSoft ok - thanks and you're welcome. i've corrected the issue you noted.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not going to rewrite the program for you, but i'll provide a tip:

you can use c++ in objc programs. specifically, you can compile as C (.c), ObjC (.m), C++ (.cpp), and ObjC++ (.mm). note: one common extension follows each language. the compiler will (by default) compile using the language implied by the file extension.

now, many java programs more closely resemble c++ programs. if you're porting a program, also consider writing it in c++ since the program will often be closer to the java variant.

for objc, you'd probably use `CF/NS-MutableData`

for c++, you can use `std::vector`

good luck

Comment: Thanks you so much.. I wrote the first one using NSMutable data but I am not sure how to read it back. It could've been easier if I added only on data into the buffer but this time I added total three different data. Could you give me some idea how to read those back from byte data?

Comment: @LCYSoft ok, since you expanded your answer and put in some extra effort: see my other answer for a starting point. but please edit it if you find an error. sorry, busy atm.